# Adding functions with jquery replace() markup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery replace() putting in list items that I want to attach a function to. I don't know exactly how to do this though.

```
function replaceListItems(){ $('ul.options').replaceWith('<ul class="options"><li class="btn"><img src="btn.png" /></li></ul>');}
```

Here's the function I'd like to attach:

```
$("ul.options li").click(function(){myFunction()});
```

Seems like it gets removed if I assign it before the list items gets replaced/created.

Thanks in advance for the help!
-m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
$("ul.options li").click(function(){myFunction()});
```

with:

```
$("ul.options li").live('click',function(){myFunction()});
```

this way jQuery also attaches the click handler to the replaced/created elements.

**Reference**: http://api.jquery.com/live/

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/CWH4D/

Answer (score 0):

#### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/epopeq/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
function replaceListItems(){     
  $('ul.options').replaceWith('<ul class="options"><li class="btn"><img src="http://placehold.it/40x40/cf5&text=BTN" /></li></ul>');       
}

$("ul.options").on('click','li',function(){  
  replaceListItems();   
});
```

More on: http://api.jquery.com/on/